# How to pbpaste in .bash_profile alias?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I try to make a small alias script to automatically reset my OS X Fuse connection.

If I run this command in my terminal:

```
pgrep sshfs|pbcopy; kill -9 $(pbpaste);echo my_password|pbcopy; sudo
umount path/to/my/mount/folder;
```

it works perfectly. If I however add it to my .bash_profile as an alias:

```
alias mount-reset="pgrep sshfs|pbcopy; kill -9 $(pbpaste);echo my_password|pbcopy; sudo umount path/to/my/mount/folder;"
```

It jumps over the pbpaste command and echoes my_password. I always thought that the alias commands are executed exactly as if I would write them to the terminal, but why is this not working? How do I pbpaste in alias script? What fundamentals have I understood wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the alias in single-quotes, rather than double-quotes. The relevant difference is that bash expands `$something` (including `$(command)`) inside double-quotes *before* executing the command. The way you have it at the moment, `pbpaste` is executed *when .bash_profile runs*, and whatever happens to be in the paste buffer at that time gets included in the alias. With single-quotes, it includes `$(pbpaste)` directly in the alias, so it gets expanded when you use the alias.

```
alias mount-reset='pgrep sshfs|pbcopy; kill -9 $(pbpaste);echo my_password|pbcopy; sudo umount path/to/my/mount/folder;'
```

However, there's an easier way. I don't see any reason to pass the sshfs PID through the paste buffer; just use include it directly:

```
alias mount-reset='kill -9 $(pgrep sshfs);echo my_password|pbcopy; sudo umount path/to/my/mount/folder;'
```

...but that's still more complicated than it needs to be, because OS X includes a `killall` command which kills processes by name, thus eliminating the need to pgrep:

```
alias mount-reset='killall -9 sshfs;echo my_password|pbcopy; sudo umount path/to/my/mount/folder;'
```

(BTW, some unixes include a command named `killall` that [does something much more dangerous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall) -- this alias is *not* portable!)

Answer (score 0):

In OS X alias commands should be added to `~/.bashrc`

When bash is an interactive non-login shell it uses `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile`. If bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, it uses `.bash_profile`, not `.bashrc`.

Try adding the alias to `~/.bashrc`. If you wanted to add a `mount-reset` command as an interactive login shell command into `~/.bash_profile` you could use something like this:

```
# kill sshfs
mount-reset () { pgrep sshfs|pbcopy; kill -9 $(pbpaste); echo my_password|pbcopy;
sudo umount path/to/my/mount/folder; }
```